# Ubuntu 16.04 D-Link N150 Pico Wi-Fi adapter doesn't work

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, d-link

I bought a new D-Link N150 Pico DWA-121 Wi-Fi adapter (although it turns out, the model is actually a few years old by now) and it doesn't work out of the box. This has me fretting, since I've seen a few notes of it working ...

I've tried the D-Link drivers for Linux found [here](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-121) without being able to install them. Neither did ndisgtk and the Windows drivers found on the same page work.

The device is detected, but that's about it:

```
    :~$ lsusb
    Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2001:331b D-Link Corp.
```

lshw -class network gives me nothing but stuff about Ethernet interface (which I assume isn't relevant) and rfkill list all yields nothing (is that unusual?)

The chipset ussed is RTL8188eu.ndi, at least judging from this line in one of the Windows driver included on the accompanying disc:

```
    %DLINK_331B.DeviceDesc%         = RTL8188eu.ndi,    USB\VID_2001&PID_331B
```

Comment: Did this have a CD with Windows drivers on it?  If it did, search through the files to find the .inf files and search them for 331b and it might tell us what chipset your device is using

Comment: @Jeremy31 It did have a CD with Windows drivers on it.  I believe the .inf file is telling me that chipset is RTL8188.eu.ndi. I'll edit my original question with this finding too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the driver, do the following in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Reboot

You will need to have Secure Boot disable in UEFI/BIOS settings